# flooring values does not calculate to 100 percent

Tags: php

```
--------------------------
Fruit                Trees
--------------------------
Apple                1098
Banana                500
Grapes                460
--------------------------
TOTAL                2058
--------------------------
```

Now, I want to find out, in form of percentage, how many trees are there for each fruit type. So, this is what I did

```
---------------------------------------------------------
 Apple              floor((1098*100)/2058)          53%
 Banana             floor(( 500*100)/2058)          24%
 Grapes             floor(( 460*100)/2058)          22%
---------------------------------------------------------
 TOTAL                                              99%
```

**As you can see, 1% is lost in flooring values**

I need logic in a way that whatever the values are for each fruit, total should get to 100%.
**Above one is SAMPLE DATA, number of tree for each fruit, and number of fruits can increase or decrease.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `round()` instead of `floor()`?

But always be careful with adding rounded numbers or percentages. Better use the original values to calculate the total.

Comment: I would try to increase that percentage precision, showing up 53.4% instead only 53%. Still, you may got only 99.9%, but do as @vindia said: use original values to calculate that final sum

Comment: Round really isn't an option! 
13, 40, 13 = 66
rounded percentages:
20%, 61%, 20% = 100%

You should calculate rounded percentages for every item except the largest. The largest should fill up the gap. In this case 20% and 20% makes 40%, so the largest number fills up to 100%: 60%.

This minimizes the error.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `round()`. both `floor` and `ceil` won't be accurate to 100%.

This will cause some percentages to be higher then they actually are, and some lower. But seeing as you already lower percentages as they are, I doubt that is an issue.

Comment: All percentages added would match 100% using round if the total value is the same as the divider.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are still certain cases where ROUND will not work perfectly.  For example:

If the raw percentages were:

Apples 50.40
Bananas 30.40
Grapes 19.20

All three of those values would round down and you would be left with only 99% total.

You still need some mechanism to check for a total of 100% and add/subtract percentages from certain values if need be.